# Could unlink(__FILE__) delete multiple files and folders?

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a line of code in a plugin I've constructed that contains these lines:

```
if (time() > 1459382400) {
    unlink(__DIR__ . '/specific-subfolder-name/specific-file.class.php');
    unlink(__FILE__);
}
```

Is there **any way** either one of these commands could delete multiple files and folders?
If so, how would it happen?

Potentially relevant details:
1. I do not know the OS or web server (Windows, Linux, Mac, Apache, IIS, ???)
2. That timestamp is March 31, 2016 (this question is posted / the code ran March 25, 2016)
3. This code *is not* in any loop, recursion, or other mechanism that would have caused it to run multiple times.
4. This code lives in `/wp-plugins/plugin-name/plugin-file.php`.  Files in root, as well as `/wp-content/*` and `/wp-admin/*` allegedly got vaped.

Comment: use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of `/`

Comment: It can only delete one file at a time. `Unlink` won't remove a directory even. There's a higher probability it won't do anything (on unprivileged shared hosting).

Comment: @Santa'shelper - good point.  Thanks.

Comment: @mario - that's what I thought, but I figured asking the genius SO community wouldn't hurt.  Maybe I missed something!